# Paragraph-style footnotes with bigfoot and (pdf)lscape

Tags: footnotes, landscape

I'm using the package `bigfoot` to declare a custom type of footnote: Thanks to the option `[para]`, the footnotes of this new type will be grouped into a single paragraph. This new type of footnote can be used alongside the usual type. This works well on regular pages but does not while in `landscape` mode. The result is that the footnotes appear on a separate page, at a slightly strange place. How do I get this working?

(The goal is to have traditional footnotes on portrait pages, but compact footnotes on landscape pages.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{bigfoot} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}

\begin{document}

At vero\footnote{One.} eos\footnote{Two.} et\footnote{Three.} accusamus\footnote{Four.} et iusto odio ...

\begin{landscape} 

At vero\footnoteB{One.} eos\footnoteB{Two.} et\footnoteB{Three.} accusamus\footnoteB{Four.} et iusto odio ...

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you may have discovered a genuine bug in the `bigfoot` package. You may want to send David Kastrup (dak at gnu dot org), the creator of this package, an email message about this and ask him for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bug in `lscape.sty`.  Move the two `\let` lines before the first `\clearpage` in the definition of `\landscape`.